# What frameworks to use to develop full and secure dynamic web application with node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

What frameworks to use to develop dynamic web application with node.js and what books to read or articles? Can you recommend full stack

Comment: Any framework or language will work if you invest the time...

Comment: @SimpleCoder While ultimately true some combinations require considerably more time (and pain/annoyances) for the same results... and I have only so much time (and dislike pain/annoyances).

Comment: I completely agree. The only reason I gave an unhelpful answer was because the asker didn't specify any preferences (besides using node and being "secure"). No mention about pain or annoyances either :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

express.js is one of the more popular frameworks for node.js so I would look into that: http://expressjs.com/

nodetuts will have some tutorials on express.js and just node in general: http://nodetuts.com/